# Change NavigationCacheMode during page life

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have Page where each time you go to this page you get new Instance of this page. But there is one navigation that when you go there, after you call

```
Frame.GoBack();
```

You will go previous page, not to new Instance of previous page.

I tried setting

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

After clicking/tapping the navigation button - but it did not work. It still creates new Instance of previous page.

I will appreciate any suggestions.Thanks

Comment: As far as I have used we need to set this property at frame creation. So I think you should put this in App constructor.

Comment: When I use it In Creation - how can I remove the page from Cache Memory ? Because when I navigate to page of the same type (not using backstack) It does not create new instance it navigate to the first page created.

Comment: You can clear the cache by setting the cache size 0. For it [Check this link](http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/). It states such scenrio. It might help you.

Comment: Yes I is exacly what I was looking for. Thanks